# Oozie spark action Log4j configuration

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform, oozie-coordinator

I am working on `Oozie`, using a `Spark` action on a `Hortonworks2.5` cluster. I have configured this job in `yarn client mode`, with `master=yarn mode=client`. 
My `log4j` configuration is shown below.

```
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=/opt/appName/logs/appNameInfo.log
log4j.appender.debugFileAppender.File=/opt/appName/logs/appNameDebug.log
log4j.appender.errorFileAppender.File=/opt/appName/logs/appNameError.log
```

The job expectation is once we trigger `oozie` job, in the above locations we should be able to see my application logs as `Info,Debug,Error` respectively.

Below is my `spark-opts` tag in my `workflow.xml`

```
<spark-opts>--driver-memory 4G --executor-memory 4G --num-executors 6 --executor-cores 3 --files /tmp/logs/appName/log4j.properties --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/tmp/logs/appName/log4j.properties' --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions='-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/tmp/logs/appName/log4j.properties'</spark-opts>
```

Once I trigger `oozie` coordinator, I am not able to see my application logs in `/opt/appName/logs/` as configured in `log4j.properties`.

The same configuration is working with plain `Spark-submit` when I run from the node where `/tmp/logs/appName/log4j.properties` available in that particular node. Can some one please look in to the issue. It is not able to write to the location which is configured in `log4j.properties` file.

Is this `log4j.properties` file should be in `hdfs`?? if so, how to provide in `spark-opts`. is it would be `hdfs://` ??

Can some one look in to the issue please?

Comment: Did your issue resolve ?

Answer (score 1):

Copy this log4j.properties in oozie.sharelib.path(HDFS) and the spark should be able to copy in the final yarn container.